# Solutions to differential equation $\nabla f(x)=f(x)x$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Let us consider the differential equation  given by $\nabla f(x)=f(x)x$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. I have found that $f(x)=K\exp(|x|^2/2)$ is a solution, but are all solution of this form?

Comment: $\nabla$ is a vector operator. How can it be equal to $f(x)x$. Probably you meant $\nabla f(\vec{r}) =f(\vec{r})\vec{r}$

Comment: Yes, nabla is a vector operator. And $f(x)x$ is a vector too. Where is the problem?

Comment: You have to give the vector sign or make it bold.

Comment: I don't agree with you. It is clear that $x$ is a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the method of integrating factor to prove that this is the only solution. Moving everything to one side, notice that

$$\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)(\nabla f - x f) = 0 \implies \nabla \left(\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) f\right) = 0$$

which means

$$f(x) = K\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$